# Java - run a process in a loop

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

I want to run a `Process` in a loop using `ProcessBuilder`:

```
    system.out.println(m_sizeOfEnv); // 2
    Process process;
    for(int i =0 ; i < m_sizeOfEnv; i++){
       ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(pathTo); //path to .sh file
       process = pb.start();

       BufferReader br = new BufferReader(new InputStreamReadser (process.getInputStream())); // print only once
       String line = null;
       while((line = br.readLine())!=null ){
          system.out.println(line); // prints the process output
       }

       process.destroy();
    }
```

The loop runs `m_sizeOfEnv` times but the process only runs once.
Why?

Comment: No, just forgot to write it here.

Comment: How do you determine the process runs only once? Could it be the other runs just don't do anything because of missing data, conditions not met etc.?

Comment: By 'BufferReader' for the process.getInputStream(). it only shown once. And it prints some data bootstrap to any process.

Comment: i checked it and work fine for me .i change pathTo to notepad and tested .

Comment: Have you tried adding process.waitFor();?

Comment: I want to start a new process.

Comment: Yes, its creating a new one, on every iteration.

Comment: You might want to provide some more information/code - currently we'd have to guess what's going on as you certainly can tell.

Comment: OK editing in a few minutes.Thanks.

Comment: @itsik mauyhas what is the program you a tring to run? some programe can have only one instance

Comment: @FastSnail A simple .sh file. does it matter?

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas not sure i don't know about Linux .but your code works for me .so problem should be either u a not reading responses correctly or program cannot have multiple instance

Comment: It works fine, thank you all.